# Strlen & Strcpy function conflict

Tags: c

I was practicing in C gcc compiler for Strings and I got the below confusion between strlen and strcopy please tell me what kind of behavior it is?
When I run my below Program without using Strlen function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k;
    char p[5];
    char p1[10];

    printf("Enter String in p");
    gets(p);

    printf("String is %s\n",p);

    strcpy(p1,p);

    puts(p1);

    puts(p);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Enter String in pshadab qureshi
String is shadab qureshi
shadab qureshi
eshi
```

and When I Run Program Using Strlen Function like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k;
    char p[5];
    char p1[10];

    printf("Enter String in p");
    gets(p);

    printf("String is %s\n",p);

    k=strlen(p);

    strcpy(p1,p);

    puts(p1);

    puts(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Then the output is:

```
Enter String in pshadab qureshi
String is shadab qureshi
shada
shada
```

please explain me the behavior why is this happening?

Comment: Good illustration of why using `gets` is bad.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by writing beyond the buffer. You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11.

Comment: [Never use `gets()`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10077)

Comment: "pshadab qureshi" is longer than the 4 characters *p* can contains (minus 1 for null char), so *gets* writes after the array with an undefined behavior as already said

Comment: Then How Can I take space in string without gets or fgets @FredLarson

Comment: @SumitAgrawal: `fgets()` is fine, though your buffer is still smaller than the text you are entering. `gets()` is disaster.